# prismic sm --setup: no such file or directory when running

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, next.js, prismic.io

I'm using prismic and trying to get setup. It says to run:

```
prismic sm --setup
```

But I get an error that no file or directory exists. I'm using it with Next.js.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you running the command from within the Next.js project folder?

Comment: Yeah i am, The root of the app

Comment: Hey! Which version of the CLI are you using?
You can see which version you are using by doing `prismic --version`